# Add padding to slide for Swiper

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I'd like to add padding to the slide, Swiper offers the parameter `spaceBetween` for outside the slide ( the wrapper gap ). Now I need padding inside the slide, I've tried adding the padding to `.swiper-slide` but it broke the whole structure of the swiper.

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 2,
  spaceBetween: 30
});
```

```css
.swiper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.swiper-slide {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should give `padding` and `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `.swiper-slide`
do this :

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 2,
  spaceBetween: 30
});
```

```css
.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background-color: green;
  position:relative;
  color: white;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.padding{
  max-width:100%;
background:red;
}
.swiper-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="padding">Slide 1</div>
    <div>example 1</div>
    <div>example 2</div>
    <div>example 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But the official demo doesn't need to add an extra div inside the slide, you might refer to it here: https://swiperjs.com/demos/360-parallax/core

Comment: add ```box-sizing : border-box;``` to ```.swiper-slide```

Comment: it'll do the trick